# Filter for datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning

I wish to have a filter for my LWC such as the ones present on list views. Does salesforce provied such filtering option out of the box or do I need to code for it using button-icon and onclick method? I did not find any help in [component reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example) of LWC.

[image: salesforce filter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code your own filter button as it does not exist out of the box